# Is there any tool that can be used to backup and restore individual schemas and not the entire database?

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, database-backups

Can someone help me with any tool that can be used to incrementally back up the individual schemas and restore them instead of backing up the entire DB? We need this for the Aurora MySQL DB RDS instances.
We already have the DB backup setup, but we want to have something at the schema level so that we can narrow down the restore points.

Comment: *back up the individual schemas and restore them instead of backing up the entire DB* ??? In MySQL the terms "schema" and "database" are synonims.

Comment: Theoretically, I think you might be able to do this with the bin logs, but I've never tried.

Comment: @SimonGoater A binlog solution is not reliable. Each binlog event names a db, but it's not the db of the change. It's the default db that was selected with `USE` at the time of the event. Also how would you deal with statement based binlogs that update multiple tables in the same SQL statement (e.g. `UPDATE db1.table1 JOIN db2.table2 ...`).

Comment: This question belongs on dba.stackexchange.com, since it is about a database operation problem, not a coding problem.

Comment: Thank you all for the comments, let me post the question on dba.stackexchange.com then.

Comment: It would be off-topic on [dba.se] too, as it's a tool/product recommendation question.